# Question about Change of Variables Proof

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

To prove change of variables in Differential geometry, we first prove the following lemma:

> Lemma 1. Suppose that the change of variables theorem holds for the diffeomorphisms $g:U\to V$ and $h: V\to W$ (and all of $f$). Then it also holds for $h\circ g: U\to W$ (for all $f$).
>   Proof: (1)
>   $\\
>  \int_W f=
> \\(2) \int_V(f\circ h)|\det Dh|=
> \\
> (3)\int_U(f\circ h \circ g))|(\det Dh)\circ g||\det Dg|=
> \\
> (4)\int_U (f\circ h\circ g))|(\det D(h\circ g)| \text{ (by the chain rule}).$
>   $\\$

These are the notes my professor gave. The part of this proof I don't understand is getting from (2) to (3) because I don't totally understand $|\det Dh|$. I know that $\det Dh$ will be the function obtained from taking the derivative of the diffeomorphism $h$, and we know $\det Dh\neq 0$. But then what do we know about $|\det Dh|$? Is this function continuous? How are we guaranteeing that when I multiply $|\det Dh|$ with the continuous function $(f\circ g)$ that I still have some continuous function that I can apply the change of variables theorem to?

I'm brand new to differential geometry, so feel free to talk to me as if I don't know what I'm talking about! :D 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us investigate the expression $|\det Dh|$ you pointed out as a possible obstacle in your understanding. Specifically, if we $h$ being a diffeomorphism implies that $|\det Dh|$ is smooth.

We assume $h \colon V \rightarrow W$ is a diffeomorphism. This means that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial h^i}{\partial x^j}$ are smooth functions for all $i,j \in \{1,..,n \}$ (where $n = \dim U = \dim V = \dim W)$. The differential $Dh$ may be represented via the Jacobian matrix of $h$. Entries of this matrix are the partial derivatives, i.e. $(Dh)_j^i =  \frac{\partial h^i}{\partial x^j}$. The expression $\det Dh$ is the determinant of $Dh$, that is, a polynomial with monomials given by products of the partial derivatives. Lets see why the implication $$h \text{ smooth } \Rightarrow \det Dh \text{ smooth}$$ holds.

Because a product of arbitrary smooth functions is a smooth function (consequence of the product rule), the monomials in $\det Dh$  must be smooth. Observe that any polynomial is given be the sum of its monomials and that a finite sum of smooth functions is a smooth function. Thus we know $\det Dh$ is a smooth function. Now we will make clear why the following holds $$h \text{ diffeomorphism } \Rightarrow |\det Dh| \text{ smooth.} $$

Because $h$ is a diffeomorphism, corresponding $Dh$ is a regular matrix, meaning: $\det Dh \neq 0$ holds on the whole domain of $h$. This implies that $\det Dh$ is always either positive or negative, therefore applying absolute value function on $\det Dh$ will not violate the smoothness. We conclude that $|\det Dh|$ is smooth.

Comment: Wow great answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

yes the scalar valued function det Dh is a sum of products of+-1 and partial derivatives the h_i's where h = (h_1,h_2,...h_n) so is continuous  so |det(Dh)| is also continuous and it's product with the continuous f0g is also continuous .So you are fine getting from (2) to (3) by applying the theorem to g .

Comment: Is it a scalar because of the absolute values? Sorry I realize this is a really basic question.

Comment: No ,no , Dh(x) is represented  by the matrix who's i^th row are the.   partial derivatives of h_i evaluated at x  .and it's determinant is a number ,so det (Dh) (x) is a real number ..